# three.js How to rotate an object around the camera coordinate?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

```
var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject(element);

object.matrix=camera.matrix.clone();

object.matrix.setPosition(new THREE.Vector3(tarx,tary,tarz));

//object.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(rY));
//object.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(rX));
```

It will rotate about the world coordinate Y,but I just want to rotate about the camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Create an object who copy camera.position (like you have done)
2 - Add a satellite to this object

```js
var orbit = 100;

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
satellite = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
satellite.position.set(orbit,0,0);
```

Add satellite to object

```
object.add( satellite );
```

If you rotate **object** 
 the satellite rotate around the camera coordinate.